# UK Fiance visa: Do I need a Property Inspection Report?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, uk-visa, family

Here is a list of things my fiance and I have as proof of Accommodation for his apartment that he owns and lives in:

- Title deed
- Council tax bill (stating he's the only one who lives there)
- Utility bills
- Photos of the apartment
- Mortgage Statement
- Floor Plan from housing developers when he purchased it along with    plot    outline (it's a new build, 6 months old)

With this in mind, is a Property Inspection Report/Surveys Report absolutely necessary? We would like to avoid spending even more money when we already have plenty of proof... Thanks.

Comment: Is it just you? Are there any children involved?

Comment: It's just me, no children.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is not 'absolutely required'. It is one of several items listed in the [Supporting Documents Guidance](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/270197/sup-docs-settlement.pdf), and you have already prepared several of those:

- Land Registry documents
- *mortgage statements* *
- rent book or tenancy agreement
- *council tax statements* *
- property inspection report
- *utilities bills* *
- *accommodation details with a supporting letter (Your floor plan and photos)* *

It's just my opinion, but I believe your evidence should more than suffice.

Comment: Thank you! I think you're right, we just needed a second opinion.